# Ruby - How can I write this lines better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is my comment controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @comment = @book.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    redirect_to book_path(@book)
  end
 
  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :content, :user_id, :book_id)
    end
end
```

I don't like the way I write `@comment.user_id = current_user.id` and `@comment.save`.
I tried to change the `@comment = @book.comments.build(comment_params)` line into `@comment = @book.user.comments.build(comment_params)` and not add the first two lines I mentioned, but that didn't work. How can I write this better? Can I add something in models and not write these two lines in comments controller?

User can comment on books.
Here are the models and the relations,
book.rb:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :author, presence: true

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :set_username
 
  has_many :books
  has_many :comments

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  attr_writer :login

  def login
    @login || self.username || self.email
  end

  private
  def set_username   
    self.username = self.email.split("@").first
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      if conditions[:username].nil?
        where(conditions).first
      else
        where(username: conditions[:username]).first
      end
    end
  end
  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already set the `user_id` in the `comment_params` method:

```
def create
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @comment = @book.comments.create(comment_params)

  redirect_to book_path(@book)
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment)
        .merge(user_id: current_user.id)
        .permit(:title, :content, :user_id)
end
```